# Invisible 'always on-top' window on bottom right of screen (Windows 10 Anniversary Update)

Tags: windows, windows-10

So, for some time now I am noticing an invisible window in the bottom right corner of my screen. How I know it's there, well.. I can't click on anything else that is located there. Right mouse button brings a menu with unclickable back and forward options and clickable reload option (see pic).

So in pictures:

Casually browsing and clicking right-button on the mouse brings me the usual menu.

[image]

I go to the bottom right and click the right-mouse-button and a menu with 'back, forward and reload' shows up from the invisible window, left click and drag does nothing...

[image]

Same thing happens in the desktop and everywhere else I go and do. This invisible window is always on top which is annoying because I can't click what I want to click if it's behind the invisible window.

I've tried almost everything from alt-tabbing to checking task manager and nothing seems to work. It even happens when I have no windows open.

I've noticed that it happened ever since the Windows 10 anniversary update. Sometimes it's there sometimes it's not

Any ideas what might be causing this?

Comment: What happens when you restart the system?

Comment: When I restart it's gone, it just happens spontaneously, one minute it's not there the next it is, I never really know what causes this.

Comment: Can you look in Task Manager after a reset and see if anything appears?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Do you have Origin installed for gaming? If so close it and restart it. Disable notifications for it, that might fix the problem.

** yes you do have origin, I see that now. :P

Comment: Did it work out?

Comment: Not OP, but I had the same problem and can confirm this works.

Comment: It's an Origin bug. Kill it and good to go!

Comment: I'm with you unable to switch solution tabs in visual studio, had to close origin.

Answer (score 0):

Had the same issue. In my case it wasn't Origin. It was an extra window from PotPlayer.

Use http://www.nirsoft.net/utils/winlister.html to find out which application is holding that area.
Check which windows are TopMost in WinLister.

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/1087201)

Answer (score 0):

Microsoft has a utility program (Process Explorer), currently available at:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/downloads/process-explorer

From the introduction:

> Ever wondered which program has a particular file or directory open? Now you can find out. Process Explorer shows you information about which handles and DLLs processes have opened or loaded.