# Unclickable area in Windows 8 - Invisible 'always on-top' window?

Tags: windows, windows-8

In the last time I often struggle with an odd issue. As of a sudden, part of the screen (usually the left 1/7th) is not clickable. You can easily see the difference when doing a right click on the desktop - once in the are which is clickable and once in the area (marked red) which is not clickable

[image: click demonstration]

So it seems there is some hidden "overlay" or invisible 'always on-top' window, which hinders me to use any control in the right area of the screen. The only think which is working is the taskbar, so I use the bottom-left are quite normally

[image: usage of taskbar is possible]

How can I fix this?

Answer (score 0):

Here, this is what you might be looking for :

[Invisible 'always on-top' window on bottom right of screen (Windows 10 Anniversary Update)](https://superuser.com/questions/1127832/invisible-always-on-top-window-on-bottom-right-of-screen-windows-10-anniversa)

If you have Origin installed, and Origin is running, you can kill it like so :

```
taskkill /f /im origin.exe /t
```

Hope this helps!

Comment: Yeah not really, this is a cooperate laptop and I obviously cannot install Origin

Answer (score 0):

After [the hint here](https://superuser.com/questions/1191524/there-is-dead-unclickable-area-in-the-mid-of-my-screen) I started to kill applications until I found the culprit. In may case it was the Slack-Desktop which caused the trouble.